# how to turn text borderline to red and error message when the input requirements are not satisfied

Tags: javascript

I'm new to this coding field. In this, my first project, I created a form and I have been able to disable the button until some numbers of input is satisfied. However, in addition, I want the borderline to turn red and also a display of some error message like "please enter a valid email" but I'm having some challenges on that. This is the already-written code:

```js
const userEmail = document.querySelector('.user-email');
const btnNext = document.querySelector('.btn-next');

emailInput.addEventListener("input", () => {
    if (emailInput.value.length > 12){
    btnNext.removeAttribute('disabled')
    }else{
    btnNext.disabled = ('disabled');
    }
});
```

```html
<form>
<input name="email" type="text" class="user-email"><br>
<input type="submit" class="btn-next">
</form>
```

Comment: The variable you set is `userEmail`, but the code sets an event listener on `emailInput` -- where is this variable coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your code like this:

```js
const userEmail = document.querySelector('.user-email');
const btnNext = document.querySelector('.btn-next');
const errorText=document.getElementById('errorText');



emailInput.addEventListener("input", () => {
    if (emailInput.value.length > 12) {
        btnNext.removeAttribute('disabled');
        errorText.innerText="";
    } else {
        btnNext.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        emailInput.style.border = '1px solid red'; 
        errorText.innerText = "Please enter a valid email";
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="user-email" placeholder="Email" id="emailInput">
<button class="btn-next" disabled>Next</button>
<p style="color:red;" id="errorText"></p>
```

Comment: both answers worked for me actually, because cos both of the answers made me understand the understand it more, but then again the effect appears immediately i input a word but i wanted it to be effective when next button is click without anything in the input box or when there less than 12 in the input box. more help will be appreciated please, and i would have checked the two answers but unfortunately only one answer is allowed to be checked.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `disabled` property is a [boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement/disabled) value. You can enable and disable the button like this:

```js
btnNext.disabled = false;
btnNext.disabled = true;
```

To change the border of the input you need to change the styles. You can do it with many ways. You can either add an extre class and handle it in css or by accessing the styles with javascript like this:

```js
// I'm guessing that the `userEmail` is your input.
userEmail.style.border = "2px solid red";
```

For the text of the error message, the easiest way is to just have an extra element under the input which initially will be empty and then when there is an error add the message there, for example:

```js
// get the element
const errorEl = document.getElementById("error-el");

// And when there is an error just modify the content of the element.
errorEl.textContent = "Please enter valid email"
```

---

**EDIT**: I edit the answer to include an answer for your question in the comments.

You seem to want to validate and style your input after the user clicks the "next" button. In that case you can just move your validation from the "input" event to the "click" event of the button.

Something like this:

```js
const nextBtn = document.getElementById("next-btn");

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if(emailInput.value.length < 11) {
    emailInput.style.border = "1px solid red";
    label.style.color = "red";
    errorText.innerText = "Please enter a valid email";
  } else {
    emailInput.style.border = "1px solid rgb(26, 115, 232)";
    label.style.color = "rgb(26, 115, 232)";
    errorText.innerText = "";
  }
})
```

I purposefully ignored the `btnNext` styles because it doesn't make sense to style it in there because you'll end up in these 2 cases probably:

1. The next button is enabled in the beginning and the user can click which seems you don't want this since you try to disable the button in your code.
2. The next button is disabled in the beginning and the user can't click, and since all the validation happens on the click, it's impossible to do something.

Form validation can be tricky. You need to think not only what to validate but when to validate. You need to be very clear about it. In your case you said:

> but then again the effect appears immediately i input a word but i wanted it to be effective when next button is click without anything in the input box or when less than 12 in the input box.

If you do what you say you want and handle validation on the next button click then it doesn't make sense for the button to be disabled at all.

Comment: okay i so much appreciate the help, i will edit it now and come back to mark the helpful one.

Comment: both answers worked for me actually, because cos both of the answers made me understand the understand it more, but then again the effect appears immediately i input a word but i wanted it to be effective when next button is click without anything in the input box or when there less than 12 in the input box. more help will be appreciated please, and i would have checked the two answers but unfortunately only one answer is allowed to be checked.

Comment: @jorgejo26 Sure, I'll try to help. Can you update your question to include more details such as your code you have until now and a little more details on what exactly you are trying to do? I'll then edit my old answer to include newer info.

Comment: @jorgejo26 I checked your code, my answer is in my edited answer above.

Answer (score 0):

*@arkatsy this is the edited code*

```
 emailInput.addEventListener("input", () => {
if (emailInput.value.length < 11){
    btnNext.disabled = true;
    emailInput.style.border = "1px solid red";
    label.style.color = "red"
    errorText.innerText = 'Please enter a valid email';
}else{
    btnNext.disabled = false;
btnNext.style.background = "rgb(26,115,232)";
emailInput.style.border = "1px solid rgb(26,115,232)";
label.style.color = "rgb(26,115,232)";
errorText.innerText = "";
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the build-in form validation. If you set the attribute `required` on the input element the form will not submit if the email is not valid. Therefore you don't need to hide or disable the submit button.

Use the `invalid` event to give the user feedback. This can be done, just by setting the class name `invalid` on the input element. When the user starts to type in the input element the validity et tested, and if the input is valid the `invalid` class name will be removed again.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.add('invalid');
}, true);

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('input', e => {
  if (e.target.validity.valid) {
    e.target.classList.remove('invalid');
  }
});
```

```css
input.invalid {
  border-color: red;
}

div.feedback {
  font-size: smaller;
  visibility: hidden;
}

input.invalid~div.feedback {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <input name="email" type="email" class="user-email" required><br>
  <div class="feedback">This is not a valid email</div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn-next">Next</button>
</form>
```